# Java, find 182.5 % (365 / 12)

Tags: java, modulo, modulus

I want to find the quotient and remainder using Java, but am having difficulty when repeating decimals are involved.

Take the following equations for example (tested with Google calculator):

```
division: 182.5 / (365 / 12) = 6
remainder: 182.5 % (365 / 12) = 0
```

Now, a simple test in Java:

```
System.out.println("division: " + 182.5 / (365.0 / 12));
System.out.println("remainder: " + 182.5 % (365.0 / 12));
```

Output:

```
division: 6.000
remainder: 30.415
```

I understand double has limitations, so I tried with BigDecimal:

```
BigDecimal daysInYear = new BigDecimal("365");
BigDecimal monthsInYear = new BigDecimal("12");
BigDecimal daysInMonth = daysInYear.divide(monthsInYear, 3, RoundingMode.CEILING);
BigDecimal daysInHalfYear = new BigDecimal("182.5");
BigDecimal division = daysInHalfYear.divide(daysInMonth, 3, RoundingMode.CEILING);
BigDecimal remainder = daysInHalfYear.remainder(daysInMonth);
System.out.println("division: " + division);
System.out.println("remainder: " + remainder);
```

Output:

```
division: 6.0
remainder: 30.41666666666666
```

What do I need to do to get the following result?

```
182.5 % (365 / 12) = 0
```

Comment: I would be mildly surprised if you could do this at all without inventing your own `Rational` class.

Comment: (The standard approach with `double` is to test "within some epsilon," you would have to manage those details yourself with a 'wrapping' operation like `%`.)

Comment: The result of the division is slightly less than 6 (but is rounded when you output it), therefore you get the remainder of 30.415.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many programming languages that have native support for accurate operations on rational numbers. Java isn't one of them. Generally this isn't a huge problem as the precision of double is enough for most applications. Remainders are an edge case where very small rounding errors can cause large unexpected results.

Your options are:

1. Use a different language
2. Use a library with support for rationals (e.g. [Rational](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/92symbolic/Rational.java.html))
3. Write your own Rational class
4. Use maths to rework your operation `x % (y / z) => (x * z % y) / z`